# Executing a function on a list and a list of lists (Erlang)

Tags: list, foreach, erlang, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have two lists:

```
Category_list = [a, b, c, d]
Id_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

For each element in Category_list and each element in the first list in Id_list I want to execute a function. Imagine I have this function:

```
Check_id(Category, ID)
```

Thus I need a function that will run check_id like this (But for a lot more IDs in reality):

```
Check_id(a, 1), Check_id(a, 2), Check_id(a, 3), Check_id(a, 4),
Check_id(b, 5), Check_id(b, 6), Check_id(b, 7), Check_id(b, 8),
Check_id(c, 9), Check_id(c, 10), Check_id(c, 11), Check_id(c, 12),
Check_id(d, 13), Check_id(d, 14), Check_id(d, 15), Check_id(d, 16).
```

The amount of elements in Category_list and the amount of elements(lists) in ID_list will always be the same. I have tried using both list comprehensions as well as the "lists:foreach" for a while now to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
check_id(C, Id) ->
    {C, Id}.

main()->
    Category_list = [a, b, c, d],
    Id_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]],

    Zip = lists:zip(Category_list, Id_list),
    Res = lists:map(fun({C, Ids}) -> [check_id(C, Id) || Id <- Ids] end, Zip),
    lists:flatten(Res).
```

You can try this method, the output is:

```
[{a,1},
 {a,2},
 {a,3},
 {a,4},
 {b,5},
 {b,6},
 {b,7},
 {b,8},
 {c,9},
 {c,10},
 {c,11},
 {c,12},
 {d,13},
 {d,14},
 {d,15},
 {d,16}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree, that you should use [PascalCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), which is camel case with capital first letter. I wouldn't bother with adding artificial indexes, though.

```
-module(category).

-compile([export_all]).

run() ->
    Category_list = [a, b, c, d],
    Id_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]],
    Zipped = lists:zip(Category_list, Id_list),
    [check_categories(Category, List) || {Category, List} <- Zipped].

check_categories(Category, List) ->
    [check_category(Category, Element) || Element <- List].

check_category(Category, Element) ->
    io:format("~p ~p~n", [Category, Element]).
```

`lists:zip/2` takes two lists and merges them into list of tuples:

```
[{a,[1,2,3,4]},{b,[5,6,7,8]},{c,"\t\n\v\f"},{d,[13,14,15,16]}]
```

Then, you can quickly scan through the tuples with {Category, ListOfElementsWithThisCategory}.

Answer (score 1):

Here is O(n) solution without indexes

```
lists:foldl(
    fun (Category, [Ids | Id_listTail]) -> 
        lists:foreach(
            fun (Id) -> 
                Check_id(Category, Id) 
            end, Ids),
        Id_listTail
    end, Id_list, Category_list),
```

This list comprehension should work for you as well:

```
%% note it's O(n^2) solution. Don't use it if Category list is much longer than in example:
[Check_id(lists:nth(N,Category_list), Id) || 
    N <-lists:seq(1,length(Category_list)), 
    Id <- lists:nth(N,Id_list)].
```

And btw it's common practice to name so called "variables" using [PascalCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase):

```
Check_id => CheckId
Category_list => CategoryList
Id_list => IdList
```

Comment: You could improve readability by naming anonymous functions and moving inner one out of foreach. Good Erlang code is nested maximally twice. Once, because you write inside a function and second time inside receive statement :) It might be extreme, but I'm usually too stupid to understand more nested code. Using `foldl` is acutally really good idea, because you are not creating auxiliary lists.

Comment: Problem with readability of nested foldl and foreach comes from sequence of parameters i believe and this is why i wrote that for function we talked some time ago - to write it in more natural manner and improve readability ;) I really like to use closures. It helps to keep modules simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The list  comprehension takes a function, a category list and a list of sublist of id and executes all the checks. It does not bring any constraint on the list and sublist sizes (except to be reasonable :o). I have added a lists:flatten/1 to present the result, but it may be useless if you don't need to collect the results.

```
1> Check_id = fun(Cat,Id) -> {Cat,Id} end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.90072148>
2> CatList = [a,b,c].
[a,b,c]
3> IdList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]].
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
4> lists:flatten([[Check_id(Cat,Id) || Cat <- CatList, Id <- SubIdList] || SubIdList <- IdList]).
[{a,1},
 {a,2},
 {a,3},
 {b,1},
 {b,2},
 {b,3},
 {c,1},
 {c,2},
 {c,3},
 {a,4},
 {a,5},
 {a,6},
 {b,4},
 {b,5},
 {b,6},
 {c,4},
 {c,5},
 {c,6}]
5>
```